# Im trying to move the cursor smoothly to random points

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, cursor-position

I'm trying to make a program that randomly moves the cursor at different points, but I don't want it just to teleport, therefore I need to make it teleport to gradual points to it's destination. I figured I could just make the x and y coord 1 and then ++ it so It looks very smooth. Would this work?

ps. sorry if I seem nooby, thats because I just learned c++ 2 weeks ago. :)

```
 class CursFluidity {
    public:

    void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
COORD coord;
coord.X = x;
coord.Y = y;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ++y);
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ++X);
}
}
```

Comment: ***Would this work?*** It could work. I recommend you try that and ask a question if you run into a problem with your implementation. You probably want a small sleep between each step otherwise it will happen so fast no one will see.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a variable to track the time (or the number of calls, or something). Let's call it `t`. You'll also need the source and destination position while you make multiple calls. Let's say:

```
class CursFluidity {
public:

    void gotoxy(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, float t);
```

Let's say you'll call this often, with `t` going from 0.0 to 1.0. Then,

```
float x = x1 * t + x0 * (1.0 - t);
float y = y1 * t + y0 * (1.0 - t);
```

will give you a point somewhere between (x0, y0) and (x1, y1) with (x0, y0) when t = 0.0 and (x1, y1) when t = 1.0.

I'll let you assemble that together and come back with specific question, as needed.